# Why only Run-time error on casting base class object to dervied class object?

Tags: c#-3.0

When I compile the following code, I only see the error during Run-time which says 
 "Unable to cast object of type 'Foo1' to type 'Foo2'"

Why is the compiler not showing this error during compile time?

```
public void Start()
{
     Foo1 objFoo1 = new Foo1();
     Foo2 objFoo2 = (Foo2)objFoo1;

     //objFoo1.FooA = 10;
     //Console.WriteLine(objFoo2.FooA);

}

public class Foo1    {}
public class Foo2 : Foo1    {}
```

Comment: Sorry. I am not able to format the code block properly. why any guess?

Comment: ok. I used code formatter. now code looks fine :)

Comment: Sorry, attempted to help format the code as well after reading your first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is not smart enough to know that `objFoo1` is really a simple `Foo1`. It doesn't analyze your source code deeply enough to determine that. All it sees is that `objFoo1` is a `Foo1`, `Foo2` is derived from `Foo1`, and therefore the cast is legal. If instead you changed that to `(int) objFoo1` it would bomb at compile-time since the compiler could see that there's no possible way to turn a `Foo1` into an integer.

Imagine that there were 1000 lines of code between the two declarations, many of them doing various assignments to `objFoo1`. The compiler would have to do a lot of hard work to attempt to determine what object exactly is in `objFoo1`. In general it wouldn't always be able to do so. It's far easier for the compiler to just take the static type information at face value and assume that `objFoo1` is some type of `Foo1` object but no more. That way it doesn't reject your simple test program but accept a more complicated one.

It's also not the compiler's job to reject your code, in this case. It is possible, though admittedly far-fetched, that you are intentionally trying to generate a `ClassCastException` by doing an illegal cast. It'd be unusual but not illegal to do that.

Along these lines, there are other cases where the compiler's static code analysis can be fooled. This will fail to compile:

```
return;
System.out.println("hello world!"); // compile error - unreachable code
```

While this will compile fine even though it is semantically identical:

```
if (true) return;
System.out.println("hello world!");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no compile time error since it is *possible* that your code could work since `objFoo1` could actually be of type `Foo2` - the compiler simply doesn't know since at execution time the actual type of the object could differ.

Remember that polymorphism allows you to reference derived types as instances of their base types - the compiler only knows and cares about is the declared type of the *reference* - in this case the reference indicates a potentially valid cast so it is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Foo2 is a Foo1. Foo1 is not a Foo2 but this is what the cast is trying to assert. The real life analogy is: typically, children inherit money from their parents but parents do not inherit money from their children.

I feel your pain here. When I first began OOP, I ran across a lot of these kinds of problems and it took me a while to wrap my head around some of the nuance. If I have a Foo1 and I want it to get the added features, why can't I just cast in the other direction and gain those extra properties and methods? Unfortunately, that's not how it works. It gets easier with time and practice though.

Answer (score -1):

its because the compiler is obeying your instruction to cast. It will then allow the code to be compiled.

```
Foo2 objFoo2 = (Foo2)objFoo1;
```

if you dont force it , it will give you a compile error.

```
Foo2 objFoo2 = objFoo1; // kaboom
```

Anyway , the real reason is that your instantiating the object Foo1, which is the base of Foo2, but not Foo2.

if you do it this way, it will work

```
Foo1 foo1 = new Foo2();
Foo2 foo2 = foo1 as Foo2;
```